# Maven compilation error: package does not exist and cannot find symbol

Tags: java, maven

I run maven using `mvn clean verify -U -e -DskipITs=true`

and get the following compilation error. When I run with the debug option -X it points me to the https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException but I cannot find the underling problem.

These packages are part of the magnolia-pages-app-5.6.4.jar with is 
 in my .m2 directory under 
/Users/asusti/.m2/repository/info/magnolia/pages/magnolia-pages-app/5.6.4/magnolia-pages-app-5.6.4.jar

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/asusti/Projects/xxx-wcms/xxx-module-versioning/src/main/java/ch/xxx/module/versioning/VersionSelector.java:[5,38] package info.magnolia.pages.app.editor does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/asusti/Projects/xxx-wcms/xxx-module-versioning/src/main/java/ch/xxx/module/versioning/VersionSelector.java:[6,48] package info.magnolia.pages.app.editor.extension does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/asusti/Projects/xxx-wcms/xxx-module-versioning/src/main/java/ch/xxx/module/versioning/VersionSelector.java:[12,38] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class AbstractExtension
[ERROR] /Users/asusti/Projects/xxx-wcms/xxx-module-versioning/src/main/java/ch/xxx/module/versioning/VersionSelector.java:[15,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class PageEditorPresenter
  location: class ch.xxx.module.versioning.VersionSelector
[ERROR] /Users/asusti/Projects/xxx-wcms/xxx-module-versioning/src/main/java/ch/xxx/module/versioning/VersionSelector.java:[18,83] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class PageEditorPresenter
  location: class ch.xxx.module.versioning.VersionSelector
```

Comment: it reads, for example, to take a look at the code in `VersionSelector.java` at line `[15,17]`. The compiler does not recognize the package or classes used within some classes of your project.

Comment: These packages are part of the magnolia-pages-app-5.6.4.jar with is in my .m2 directory under /Users/asusti/.m2/repository/info/magnolia/pages/magnolia-pages-app/5.6.4/magnolia-pages-app-5.6.4.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this into my module's pom file and after that maven worked:

```
<!-- magnolia pages extensions for pagebar functionality -->
    <dependency>
            <groupId>info.magnolia.pages</groupId>
            <artifactId>magnolia-pages-app</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
```